# LPC2148 + Eclipse + yagarto + openOCD. Issue with the interrupts

Tags: arm, interrupts, lpc, nxp

I'm using 'Eclipse-Indigo' + yagarto + 'openocd-0.7.0' setup for a project on LPC2148.

I've set up the environment properly. I'm able to compile, link and debug the project.

I've configurred Timer0 & UART1 interrupts and I'm facing problems with the same.
I've enabled IRQ interrupts through respective CPSR - IRQ bit.

For timer0 interrupts, the control hits the ISR for 1 or 2 interrupts & then control either goes to:

1. 'Undefined routine' or
2. program keeps running in the 'while(1) loop' defined in main function.

For UART1 interrupts, the control hits the ISR for first interrupt & then program keeps running in the 'while(1) loop' defined in main function.

I've checked the related register values and found that the interrupts are sensed by the controller(The correspoding interrupt bits are set).
IRQ status is enabled(checked the IRQ bit in CPSR when the code is running).

Still the control does not go to ISR even when next interrupt occurs.

Can anybody tell me the reason?

Comment: Are you accomplishing everything need to re-arm the interrupts?  For serial, do you have any error flags on the UART?  Are your code and interrupt vectors in flash, or in ram?

Comment: Could you post the code where your ISRs are defined?  Preferably with other relevant code too.

Comment: Btw: Current OpenOCD version is `0.8.0` already.